# How to overlap a layout with mapview

Tags: android, android-mapview, overlap, android-framelayout

Hello everyone I'm developing an app. I want to overlap a layout with map like image show. I added framelayout but when i playing my hand over the framelayout it affect my map. How can i solve this issue ?

Thanks in advance.

**PS: No matter context. My xml like this. But my touch on framelayout affect map too.**

My Main.XML ;

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment">

   <com.esri.android.map.MapView
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
   </com.esri.android.map.MapView>

   <FrameLayout
       android:layout_width="240dp"
       android:layout_height="400dp"
       android:background="#fcccff"
       >
   </FrameLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside your Frame layout set this attribute and let me know

```
<FrameLayout
       android:layout_width="240dp"
       android:layout_height="400dp"
       android:background="#fcccff"
android:setClickable="true"
       >
   </FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks for comment it says unknown attribute android:setClickable

Comment: But i found android:clickable attribute ? maybe it is your answer ?

Comment: It work ovv yeah. I am looking for this issue for one week . You save my project lifecycle :) You deserved check :) But one adding note i use fragment for transaction. I made fragment clickable true so my framelayout not affect map :)